# Using ssd_inception_v2 to train on different resolution

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

The dataset contains images of different sizes.
The pretrained weights are trained on 300x300 resolution.
I am training on widerface dataset where objects are as small as 15x15.

Q1. I want to train with 800x800 resolution do i need to resize all the images manually or this will be done by Tensorflow automatically ?

I am using the following command to train:

```
python3 /opt/github/models/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=/opt/github/object_detection_retraining/wider_face_checkpoint/ --pipeline_config_path=/opt/github/object_detection_retraining/models/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config
```

Q2. I also tried training it using the model_main.py but after 1000 iterations it is evaluating the dataset with each iteration.

I am using the following command to train:

```
python3 /opt/github/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py --num_train_steps=200000  --logtostderr --model_dir=/opt/github/object_detection_retraining/wider_face_checkpoint/ --pipeline_config_path=/opt/github/object_detection_retraining/models/ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/pipeline.config
```

Q3. Also if you can suggest any model i should use for real time face detection apart from mobilenet and inception, please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. No you do not need to resize manually. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56267652/is-it-required-to-have-predefined-image-size-to-use-transfer-learning-in-tensorf) detailed answer.

Q2. By 1000 iterations you meant steps right? (An iteration counts as a complete cycle of the dataset.) Usually the model performed evaluation after a certain amount of time, e.g. 10 minutes. So in every 10 minutes, the checkpoints are saved and an evaluation of the model on evaluation set is performed.

Q3. SSD models with mobilenet is one of the fast detectors, apart from that you can try YOLO models for real time detection

Comment: Extending Q2. It is possible to disable evaluation with model_main.py ?

Comment: That can actually be done by modifying the config file. In the config file under field `eval`, you can try adding `eval_interval_secs : 99999999` so that the evaluation interval is very large.  Someone tried this but it did not work well. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5801. Another solution is to save the checkpoint less frequently (the evaluation is performed after each time checkpoint is saved), so my suggestion is to change `keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours : 5000` in the field `train`.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5139#issuecomment-418963839 is another discussion about changing evaluation frequency.